# Rails 4, change logo in layout depending on user

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails-4, haml

In my app I want to change the logo and other default pictures depending on which user is logged in. Anyone has a good tutorial or know how to do this?
I have been looking for this a lot but there is no much information about it.

I have the user login system done and is possible to create new roles. Currently the roles dosen't do anything but it exist.

I'm now adding my main layout, user model and role model. What I want is to change the "wfront/logo" depending on the current user role. I think it should be simple but I'm very new at rails and this app was programed by another person.

Please tell me if you need more info.

```
views/layouts/application.html.haml
//this is my app layout and I want to change the logo dynamically 'wfront/logo'
    %html
      %head
        %title= full_page_title
        = render 'wfront/head'
        = csrf_meta_tags
      %body{ class: "fixed-header fixed-navigationx smart-style-0 #{cookies[:menu_state]}" }
        %header#header
          = render 'wfront/logo'
          = render 'wfront/context_select'
          = render 'wfront/subcontext_select'
          = render 'wfront/toggle_menu_button'
          = render 'wfront/user_info'
          .pull-right
            = render 'wfront/currency_select'
            = render 'wfront/date_select'
        %aside#left-panel
          = render 'wfront/nav_menu'
          %span.minifyme{ data: { action: 'minifyMenu' } }
            %i.fa.fa-arrow-circle-left.hit

        #main
          #ribbon
          #content
            .row
              = render 'wfront/title'
              .col-xs-12.col-sm-5.col-md-5.col-lg-7
                %ul#sparks
                  = render 'wfront/sparks'
                  = render 'wfront/exchange_rates'
            = yield

        .page-footer
          = render 'wfront/footer'

        = render 'wfront/quaam'
        = javascript_include_tag 'application', "data-turbolinks-track" => true
        = yield :scripts

        = render 'wfront/modal'
```

--

```
  models/user.rb
    # == Schema Information
    #
    # Table name: users
    #
    #  id                     :integer          not null, primary key
    #  email                  :string(255)      default(""), not null
    #  encrypted_password     :string(255)      default(""), not null
    #  reset_password_token   :string(255)
    #  reset_password_sent_at :datetime
    #  remember_created_at    :datetime
    #  sign_in_count          :integer          default(0), not null
    #  current_sign_in_at     :datetime
    #  last_sign_in_at        :datetime
    #  current_sign_in_ip     :string(255)
    #  last_sign_in_ip        :string(255)
    #  created_at             :datetime
    #  updated_at             :datetime
    #  name                   :string(255)
    #

    class User < ActiveRecord::Base
      # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
      # :confirmable, :registerable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
      devise :database_authenticatable, :lockable,
             :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

      has_many :account_users
      has_many :accounts, through: :account_users
      has_many :taxes, -> { uniq }, through: :accounts

      validates :name, :email, presence: true, uniqueness: true

      include Concerns::Roleize
      roleize

      def primary_account
        self.accounts.first
      end
    end
```

--

```
   model/role.rb
    # == Schema Information
    #
    # Table name: roles
    #
    #  id            :integer          not null, primary key
    #  name          :string(255)
    #  resource_id   :integer
    #  resource_type :string(255)
    #  created_at    :datetime
    #  updated_at    :datetime
    #

    class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :resource, polymorphic: true
      before_create :tableize_name

      def tableize_name
        self.name = self.name
      end

      def self.method_missing(name, *args, &block)
        roles = self.where(["name =?", name])
        if roles.any?
          scope roles.first.name.to_sym, ->{roles.first}
          return self.send(name.to_sym)
        end
        super
      end
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just using an if/else statement based on user.role?

```
- if @user.get_role == 'some_role'
  = render 'some-logo'
- elsif @user.get_role == 'other_role'
  = render 'other-logo'
- else
  = render 'logo'
```

user.rb

```
def get_role
  Role.where(user_id: self.id).first
end
```

Comment: I was trying to do that but I get an error with @user.role. how can I know the right way to call the role?

Comment: Ok I just noticed that since User doesn't have the association `has_one :role` you can't use `@user.role`. If you don't want that association you would have to make a method that checks if there is a role with the `resource_id: ==  @user.id` and then instead of `@user.role` run the method `@user.find_role` or whatever. Just be careful that it doesn't come back nil.

Comment: Thanks for the clear response! I add it to the code but now I have an error related to user_id: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column roles.user_id does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT  "roles".* FROM "roles"  WHERE "roles"."user_id" = 5 ...
                                              ^
: SELECT  "roles".* FROM "roles"  WHERE "roles"."user_id" = 5  ORDER BY "roles"."id" ASC LIMIT 1

Comment: So it looks like you are using :resource_id instead of :user_id. When you create the role I assume you are setting the :resource_id to the id of the user so just change `user_id: self.id` to `resource_id: self.id`